# Plesk 12 scheduled task error

Tags: apache, cron, plesk

I am trying to set a cron job where it will run php script and mail the results to user. However I am getting a permission denied error when the script is run.

```
/bin/sh: /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/bdmail.php: Permission denied
```

This is the code I am using in the command line:

```
/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/bdmail.php
```

I would be grateful if someone could highlight my error. I have setup a new task in plesk and it looks correct to me. Thanks

OS: CentOS 6 with Parallels Plesk Panel 12 (64-bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create scheduled task that calls the script interpreter with the path to the script as an option. For example:

/usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/bdmail.php

instead of just

/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/bdmail.php